Training Accuracy Raising While Validation Accuracy Fluctuating
I am trying to build a sign language action recognition model, I have frames that I transformed to landmark keypoints using Mediapipe and they are in .npy format, training gets to 90% but my validation goes to 10%, 20%, 50%, 20%, 25%, etc...
My dataset consists of 502 classes and more than 2 million images.
Below is my model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def enhanced_cnn_lstm_model(num_frames=30, num_keypoints=1662, num_classes=502):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(num_frames, num_keypoints), recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model


My data generator
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
class KeypointsDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, dataset_dir, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_frames=30, num_keypoints=1662):
        self.dataset_dir = dataset_dir
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.num_frames = num_frames
        self.num_keypoints = num_keypoints
        self.samples, self.labels = self._load_dataset()
        self.on_epoch_end()
    
    def _load_dataset(self):
        samples = []
        labels = {}
        label_idx = 0
        for label_dir in sorted(os.listdir(self.dataset_dir)):
            label_path = os.path.join(self.dataset_dir, label_dir)
            for sample_file in sorted(os.listdir(label_path)):
                sample_path = os.path.join(label_path, sample_file)
                if os.path.isfile(sample_path) and sample_path.endswith('.npy'):
                    samples.append(sample_path)
                    labels[sample_path] = label_idx
            label_idx += 1
        if not samples:
            print("No samples found.")
        return samples, labels


    
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.samples) / self.batch_size))
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch_samples = self.samples[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        X, y = self._generate_data(batch_samples)
        return X, y
    
    def _generate_data(self, batch_samples):
        X = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.num_frames, self.num_keypoints))
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size), dtype=int)
        
        for i, sample_path in enumerate(batch_samples):
            keypoints = np.load(sample_path)
            keypoints = keypoints.reshape(self.num_frames, self.num_keypoints)
            X[i,] = keypoints
            y[i] = self.labels[sample_path]
        
        return X, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=502)
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.samples)


Code used to extract keypoints
import numpy as np

def adjust_sequence_length(features_list, target_length=30):
    uniform_length = max(len(f) for f in features_list) if features_list else 0
    
    padded_features_list = [np.pad(f, (0, uniform_length - len(f)), 'constant') for f in features_list]
    
    num_frames = len(padded_features_list)
    adjusted_features = np.zeros((target_length, uniform_length))
    
    if num_frames > target_length:
        indices = np.round(np.linspace(0, num_frames - 1, target_length)).astype(int)
        adjusted_features = np.array(padded_features_list)[indices]

    elif num_frames < target_length:
        repeat_factor = target_length // num_frames
        additional_frames_needed = target_length % num_frames
        expanded_features = padded_features_list * repeat_factor + padded_features_list[:additional_frames_needed]
        adjusted_features[:len(expanded_features), :] = expanded_features

    else:
        adjusted_features = np.array(padded_features_list)
    
    return adjusted_features


mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands.Hands(static_image_mode=True, max_num_hands=2, min_detection_confidence=0.5)
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose.Pose(static_image_mode=True, min_detection_confidence=0.5)
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh.FaceMesh(static_image_mode=True, max_num_faces=1, min_detection_confidence=0.5)

for label_dir in tqdm(os.listdir(dataset_directory)):
    gesture_path = os.path.join(dataset_directory, label_dir)
    features_label_dir = os.path.join(features_root_directory, label_dir)
    os.makedirs(features_label_dir, exist_ok=True) 
    for sample_dir in os.listdir(gesture_path):
        sample_path = os.path.join(gesture_path, sample_dir)
        features_list = []
        
        for frame in sorted(os.listdir(sample_path)):
            image_path = os.path.join(sample_path, frame)
            image = cv2.imread(image_path)
            if image is not None:
                image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                features = extract_features(image_rgb, mp_hands, mp_pose, mp_face_mesh)
                if features.size > 0:
                    features_list.append(features)
        
        adjusted_features = adjust_sequence_length(features_list)
        
        save_path = os.path.join(features_label_dir, f"{sample_dir}.npy")
        np.save(save_path, adjusted_features)

mp_hands.close()
mp_pose.close()
mp_face_mesh.close()

I tried data generator with normailztion, but training accuracy gets stuck at 0.2%
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
class KeypointsDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, dataset_dir, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_frames=30, num_keypoints=1662):
        self.dataset_dir = dataset_dir
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.num_frames = num_frames
        self.num_keypoints = num_keypoints
        self.samples, self.labels = self._load_dataset()
        self.min_val, self.max_val = self._find_min_max_values()
        self.on_epoch_end()
    
    def _load_dataset(self):
        samples = []
        labels = {}
        label_idx = 0
        for label_dir in sorted(os.listdir(self.dataset_dir)):
            print(f'Processing label: {label_dir}')
            label_path = os.path.join(self.dataset_dir, label_dir)
            for sample_file in sorted(os.listdir(label_path)):
                sample_path = os.path.join(label_path, sample_file)
                if os.path.isfile(sample_path) and sample_path.endswith('.npy'):
                    samples.append(sample_path)
                    labels[sample_path] = label_idx
            label_idx += 1
        return samples, labels


    
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.samples) / self.batch_size))
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch_samples = self.samples[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        X, y = self._generate_data(batch_samples)
        return X, y
    
    def _find_min_max_values(self):
        min_vals = []
        max_vals = []
        for sample_path in self.samples:
            print(f'Processing sample: {sample_path}')
            keypoints = np.load(sample_path)
            min_vals.append(np.min(keypoints))
            max_vals.append(np.max(keypoints))
        return np.min(min_vals), np.max(max_vals)
    
    def _generate_data(self, batch_samples):
        X = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.num_frames, self.num_keypoints))
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size), dtype=int)
        for i, sample_path in enumerate(batch_samples):
            keypoints = np.load(sample_path)
            keypoints = keypoints.reshape(self.num_frames, self.num_keypoints)
            keypoints = (keypoints - self.min_val) / (self.max_val - self.min_val)  # Apply Min-Max scaling
            X[i,] = keypoints
            y[i] = self.labels[sample_path]
        return X, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=502)

    
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.samples)

I tried lower dropout rates and still the same, made the model less and more complex, I tried different learning_rate and still nothing helped.
